# Ruby on rails geocoder gem reverse-geocoding produces significant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, google-geocoder

I'm using the goecoder gem for ruby on rails and I found that accuracy is a problem with its built-in database (which I think is google goecoder). The location returned could be as much as several miles from the actual location. For the purpose of the website I'd like to have as little error as possible, so is there an alternative database option for this gem or should I resort to an entirely different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alternative services you can check out. It's listed in the [read me](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-services). In addition to Google, there's Bing, Mapquest and a bunch of other services.